# Passing a variable in a url to a PHP file

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im following a MySQL article on the basics of using HTML and PHP. The two files I have are very very basic:

Index.html:

```
<A HREF="welcome.php?name=Kevin"> Hi, I'm Kevin! </A>
```

welcome.php:

```
<?php
  echo( "Welcome to our Web site, $name!" );
?>
```

When the link is clicked on the index page, I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\welcome.php on line 2
Welcome to our Web site, !
```

Im not exactly an expert but i pretty sure the codes correct - is there any sort of setting/configuration that I shouldve completed before trying to run it which is preventing the variable being passed to the php file?

Thanks, Gio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need to use [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) to pull the "name" parameter from the URL.

```
<?php
  $name = $_GET['name'];
  echo( "Welcome to our Web site, $name!" );
?>
```

You'll also want to look into sanitizing the input to prevent against code injection using methods like [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), and check if the URL contains a "name" parameter in the first place using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['name']) {
        $name = htmlspecialchars($_GET['name']);
        echo( "Welcome to our Web site, $name!" );
    }
?>
```

Comment: ok I think that was the quickest answer to a question ever! and its sorted, so thankyou!I wonder why an article on dev.mysql.com would be incorrect?

Comment: @Giovanni I've just edited the answer to mention `isset()` as well. As for the article, no idea, perhaps you've missed a section which sets the `$name` variable?

Comment: when you say code injection, this is a security issue is it, rather than for functionality?

Comment: You'd want to stop people from doing things like `welcome.php?name=<script>/* Code to redirect page to other site */</script>`. Without using `htmlspecialchars()`, the output from your `echo` would redirect your page to another potentially malicious page. `htmlspecialchars()` simply converts characters like `<` and `>` to their entity equivalents (`&lt;` and `&gt;`).

Answer (score 2):

In your example you are using the Global Variables feature of PHP, that feature is deprecated because security.

You can use $_GET to get URL variables

```
<?php
  $name = $_GET['name']; // Gets ?name=value
?>
```

You use $_POST to retrieve data from forms submits via POST

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name']; // Get <input name="name"> value via POST
?>
```

You use $_REQUEST to retrieve data from GET or POST depending of the current request method

```
<?php
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
?>
```

Comment: I was just wondering whether it had been deprecated; ive come across issues like this in the latest iOS. The article is fairly old so this makes perfect sense, thankyou!